# Insert into MySQL Table PHP Redirect

Tags: php, sql-insert

I have simple form  to insert data into a MySQL table. I want user after click submit to go back to index.php I have 2 files index.php and insert.php

insert.php

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "");
    mysql_select_db("foster", $con);

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
        $ID=$_POST['ID'];
        $firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName=$_POST['lastName'];

            $query = mysql_query("insert into customers(ID, firstName, lastName) values ('$ID', '$firstName', '$lastName')");



     }

   ?>

    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        ID: <input type="text" name="ID"/>
        <br/>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
        <br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
        <br/>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="INSERT CUSTOMER"/>
    </form>
```

My problem is every time I change action to index.php table not change but if use action="#" is working.

Comment: of course, it will not work on `index.php`, your insertion codes are on `insert.php`

Comment: index.php !=insert.php

Comment: Is there any other way to this?

Comment: Jesus calm down guys I didn't that

Answer (score 1):

Just add this after the INSERT query:

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

It will redirect to `index.php` after the insertion

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `<form action="index.php" method="post">` to `<form action="insert.php" method="post">` as you want to insert your data in `insert.php`.
2. After inserted, jump your page to index.php.